# How to define onclick() inside dynamic content in ckeditor

Tags: onclick, ckeditor

I am trying to make a custome plugin in ckeditor. What I am trying to do is to make an ajax call to my server and get a list of items, which I dynamically present into a div. For each of these items I have set an onclick attribute. The problem is that I get an error that the function in the onclick attribute is not defined.

Code snippets below:

Dialog contents:

```
contents : [
{
            id : 'information',

            name : 'information',

            label : 'Information',

            elements : [
            {
                type:'vbox',
                padding:0,
                children:[
                {
                    type : 'html',
                    html : '<div style="width: 100%; height: 150px; float: left; border: 1px solid #666666; overflow: auto;" id="results"></div>'
                },
            ]
}]
```

List element which I insert in the div:

```
var html  = '<a onclick="showMore(' + resultNum + ')">';
        html += result;
        html += '</a>';
        return html;
```

I have tried to define showMore function with these two ways:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('popup', function(editor)
{   
    function showMore() {}
}
```

and

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('popup', function(editor)
    {   
        showMore : function() {} (in the return block)
    }
```

like onOk, etc, but not luck with both approaches.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you must define the `showMore` function in your page, not as a part of the dialog.

Comment: It is possible to dynamically create it and add it in the dialog? As it was an html item?

Comment: You're getting confused by CKEditor and the dialogs. If you add a block of HTML to a page with an onclick handler inside of it that calls a function, that function must be defined on the page. Start from scratch and test adding your html to div in a page with nothing else, just that div. When you understand how that works, the you can see easily your original problem (and how to modify it to work with any other modification, after all this is just HTML and JS).

Comment: Ok I see.. I ll try to do this and come back for feedback, etc. Thanks in advance!